# Как в qdateTimeEdit сделать смещение кнопки по вертикали?

Tags: qt

Написал вот такой код:

```
QDateTimeEdit {
     padding-top: 20px; 
     padding-bottom: 20px; 

     border-image: url("/home/image/next.png");
     border-width: 0px;

     background-clip: content;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::up-button {
     subcontrol-origin:  border;
     subcontrol-position: top center;
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
     border-image: url("/home/image/next_.png");
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::down-button {
     subcontrol-origin:  border;
     subcontrol-position: bottom center;
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }
```

Хочу перенести кнопку по вертикали вниз на определенное количество пикселей.
Как это можно сделать с применением  stylesheets?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

например для right

> If position is relative (the default), moves a subcontrol
>   by a certain offset to the left; specifying right: x is then
>   equivalent to specifying left: -x. If position is absolute, the right
>   property specifies the subcontrol's right edge in relation to the
>   parent's right edge (see also subcontrol-origin).

```
QDateTimeEdit {
     padding-top: 40px; 
     padding-bottom: 40px;  
     border-image: url("/home/image/next_.png");
     border-width: 0px;   
     background-clip: content;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::up-button {
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: top center;
     top: 15px; /*If position is relative (the default), moves a subcontrol by a certain offset down.*/
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::down-button {
     subcontrol-origin:  border;
   subcontrol-position: bottom center;
  bottom: 15px;

     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }
```

Comment: Если даже сделать 'padding-top: 0px;' то все равно кнопка не смещается вниз.  Двигаются только цифры 01.01.00 0:00.

Comment: сразу не обратил внимание. а почему subcontrol-origin:  border;? почему не margin?

Comment: Как понял border это граница виджета, а margin это внешняя сторона границы. Если написать 'subcontrol-origin:   margin;' то как сместить кнопку вниз на нужное количество пикселей ?

Comment: изменил ответ. см выше